# Illegal characters in path (Chinese characters)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Getting an "Illegal characters in path" with Directory.GetFiles:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName & invoiceFile & "*.pdf")
```

Given the actual values, the filenames would be like so:

```
x:\folder1\請 010203.pdf
y:\foldera\folderb\請 040506.pdf
z:\xyz\abc\請 119906.pdf
```

Hence the * wildcard. Can I use Chinese characters with Directory.GetFiles? I think I can since I was able to use it on a separate VBA project before using `ChrW(35531)` so I think it shouldn't be a problem with .NET. Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: what are the exact values of `folderName` and `invoiceFile` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName, invoiceFile & "*.pdf")
```

Note that the folder name and the filter are separate parameters.